# Combine 2 Foreach statements into 1 PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

Is it posible to combine 2 foreach statements into one?:

```
foreach ($this->products as $product) {
  // Content Here
}
```

and

```
foreach (range(0, 100, 10) as $number) {
  // Content Here
}
```

Like:

```
 foreach (($this->products as $product) && (range(0, 100, 3) as $number)) {
      // Content Here
    }
```

**Result:**

1 Honda

2 BMW

3 Mazda - echo "break />";

4 Volvo

5 Ferrari

6 VW  - echo "break />";

7 Opel

8 Porsche

9 Toyota  - echo "break />";

**Would look like this:**

Honda
BMW
Mazda

Volvo
Ferrari
VW

Opel
Porsche
Toyota

Comment: No, you can't. What are you trying to achieve? (maybe there are other ways to prevent a double `foreach`)

Comment: Hi thanks, i want to execute a piece of code on every tenth number in the loop. etc, in 34 products, product loops number 10, 20 and thirty will execute the additional code in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do a double `foreach`. However, based on your question and comment, you should do the following:

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($this->products as $product){
    //do stuff here
    if($counter % 10 == 0){ // % is Mod (10 mod 9 = 1, 10 mod 10 = 0)
        //item 10, 20, 30...
    }
    $counter += 1;
}
```

Using this template and [PHP arithmetic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), for how MOD works, you can make this work with any number of products to trigger the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add 10 to a certain variable, you can try this:

```
foreach($this->products AS $product) {

     //do something

     $counter += 10;

}
```

Set `$counter` to 0 before the loop starts.